# Ubuntu core - login problem-how to force reboot?

Tags: ssh, login, reboot, ubuntu-core, putty

I followed all the steps. I created a SSH key on Puttygen, and imported it to the Ubuntu One.

However, I did not create a password for my SSH key, and it is asking me a password and don't accept no password.
I am stuck on the log in screen, I can't reboot or change the config directly on the Raspberry Pi 3, or load a new SSH key.
What should I do?

Comment: If it's asking for a pass*word* rather than a pass*phrase*, then it sounds like SSH is defaulting to non-key based authentication (possibly because the format of the PuTTY key is not compatible with OpenSSH).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reboot:
Hold down alt and sys-req keys simultaneously. Continue to hold them down while you press the following sequence, waiting several seconds between each key press:
r
e
i
s
u
b

The mnemonic usually used is "Raising elephants is so utterly boring."

If that fails, try the soft switch. If it still doesn't work, maybe pull the plug and wait for the batteries to run down, and hope the power management software will shut it down gracefully.

Comment: alt and sys-req keys,  can also do other things.
However it did not solve the problem with the SSH key. I really don't understand why it is not accepting the password that I saved with my key.
It is the same proccess I have been using for a million of other things that I use SSH.

Comment: Wasn't aiming at "solve the problem with the SSH key", just trying to answer "how to force the reboot?" with 3 options in order of preference. No guarantee on any of them except the last, and even on it, no guarantee it will shutdown gracefully, but it would seem to have a chance of it. Were you able to reboot with either of the first 2? OHHH. You are trying to do it REMOTELY? Sorry, I didn't catch that. Then nothing I said is relevant. Sorry.